# Check if Windows file is redirected to itself

Tags: windows, go, stdout, io-redirection

I'm trying to figure out how I can test if a file is being redirected to itself, e.g. `.\command.exe file1 > file1`

In the *nix world, I'd just use something like this:

```c
// Language agnostic...
if (file_dev == out_dev && file_ino == out_ino) {
    printf("%s\n", "same file!");
}
```

But in Windows, if I try to do this:

```go
// This (language) is Go...
// create fileStat...

// now stat stdout
outStat, err := os.Stdout.Stat()
// error check

if os.SameFile(fileStat, outStat) {
    fmt.Println("same file!")
}
```

...I get the `IncorrectFunction` error.

I read this ([How to check if stdout has been redirected to NUL on Windows (a.k.a. /dev/null on Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21069853/995714)) question, and from what I gather you can't stat `stdout`?

This is a mostly language agnostic question -- I can translate whatever to Go (the language I'm using). I'm mostly concerned about *how*, using Windows' ABI (API?), I would find where stdout is being redirected to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2912665/garg-ankit I rejected your edit because this is about Windows' A{B,P}I not Go... sorry.

Comment: That's okay. Makes sense to me after re-reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is Windows-specific but as you've tagged [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) I figure that's ok.

I can't help with Go, but in C/C++ you can do something like this:

```c
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t chPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetFinalPathNameByHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), chPath, MAX_PATH, 0))
        std::wcout << L"stdout = " << chPath << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "stdout not redirected" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`GetFinalPathNameByHandle` will fail if stdout is a console handle, but if it's been redirected to a file it will return the file path.

Comment: I suppose that answers the specific question asked but I still don't think it'll do any good, due to the reasons covered in my answer. By the time you detect it, it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`HANDLE GetStdHandle( DWORD stdHandle )` with `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) to open the file handle.

Then call [`DWORD GetFileType( HANDLE hFile )` to check if the returned type is `FILE_TYPE_DISK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype)

Finally, call

[`DWORD WINAPI GetFinalPathNameByHandle( _In_   HANDLE hFile, _Out_  LPTSTR lpszFilePath, _In_   DWORD cchFilePath, _In_   DWORD dwFlags );`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea)

to obtain the file pathname and compare the names for equivalency.

Comment: It worked! I accepted Jonathan's because his came first -- hope you understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, I don't think your method in UNIX-land is *actually* going to protect you.

By the time your code gets to checking devices and inodes, the shell has *already* truncated the file. *It* is responsible for processing the output redirections and it does this *before* your program even starts, so that you're given a fresh file for your output.

I suspect you'd have the same problem in Windows in that `cmd.exe` will truncate your file before your script even started running.

Having said that, I believe at some point you're going to have to trust that the user knows what they're doing :-)

The other alternative is, of course, not to *do* output redirection but instead to require the input and output files as arguments:

```
cmd.exe myscipt myscript
```

That way, you could detect if the user was going to write to the input file (using canonicalised file names or inodes) and prevent it.

Although that *still* won't prevent the user from doing something silly like:

```
cmd.exe myscipt >myscript
```

blowing away your script *before* you get a chance to notify them they should have provided two arguments rather than one.

I think the bottom line is, if the user does output redirection, there's no way for your *program* to catch it before it's too late.

Comment: The first part (truncation) is true and I know that. :-) It's mostly for my sake because I'm transliterating GNU's coreutils from C to Go, and I want them to be *as* similar as possible. It also protects against something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26112133/2967113

Comment: @eric, I'm not _entirely_ sure what you think your scheme will protect against, it's won't do so with something like a script overwriting itself: `script >script` because, as stated, the overwrite happens long before the script starts running. Perhaps you could explain more.

Comment: With BSD `cat` you could cause an infinite loop if you do something like `cat file1 file2 > file2`. Really, that's not such a big deal. But it (the check) is a part of GNU `cat`, and that's the `cat` I'm copying, so I want to include it!